# Why can you do df.loc(False)['value'] in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I do not see any documentation on pandas explaining the parameter False passed into loc. Can anyone explain how () and [] differ in this case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`df.loc` is an instance of the [`_LocIndexer`](https://github.com/margaret/pandas/blob/d13082430513a0ebcb61f0c4ad79eebeab27194f/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1368) class, which happens to be a subclass of the [`_NDFrameIndexer`](https://github.com/margaret/pandas/blob/d13082430513a0ebcb61f0c4ad79eebeab27194f/pandas/core/indexing.py#L88) class.

When you do `df.loc(...)`, it would seem the [`__call__`](https://github.com/margaret/pandas/blob/d13082430513a0ebcb61f0c4ad79eebeab27194f/pandas/core/indexing.py#L98) method is invoked which harmlessly returns another instance of itself. For example:

```
In [641]: df.loc
Out[641]: <pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer at 0x10eb5f240>

In [642]: df.loc()()()()()()
Out[642]: <pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer at 0x10eb5fe10>

...
```

And so on. The value passed in `(...)` is not used by the instance in any way.

On the other hand, the attributes passed to `[...]` are sent to [`__getitem__`](https://github.com/margaret/pandas/blob/d13082430513a0ebcb61f0c4ad79eebeab27194f/pandas/core/indexing.py#L108)/[`__setitem__`](https://github.com/margaret/pandas/blob/d13082430513a0ebcb61f0c4ad79eebeab27194f/pandas/core/indexing.py#L173) which does the retrieval/setting.

Comment: Or assignment via `__setitem__`. OP did not specify.

Comment: typically, what are the parameters that can be included in .loc(...) then?

Comment: @user1559897 You can pass whatever you want, as long as it is a single parameter, because it is ignored.

Comment: @COLDSPEED it is ignored for `df.loc` indeed, but not for all indexing methods.

Comment: It's better stated that you shouldn't pass anything to `loc` via it's `__call__` method because it gets ignored and is not what was intended at all.  `[]` was intended to get used, so use it.  `()` was not, so don't.

Comment: @piRSquared I see. Is this mentioned somewhere in the docs? The reason I started this bounty was because 50% of this answer is my own speculation/inference from stalking the git repo.

Comment: I was responding to @Uvar.  This question is about `loc` not other indexing methods.  I thought you stated things pretty well.  And no, I don't know anymore than you on this particular subject.  What you've said already is consistent with my set of knowledge.

Comment: Fair enough @piRSquared
@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ : in my answer below (which I only bothered with to answer this particular question, as OPs question was sufficiently answered already), I went through my inference from going through the code. The only reason `loc` even has a `__call__` method is because of class compatibility with `ix` . For `loc` and `iloc` the `__call__` method is ignored and the member set by it overridden by default `axis=0` in all cases.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers already explain, the `()` braces invokes the `__call__` method, which is defined as:

```
def __call__(self, axis=None):
    # we need to return a copy of ourselves
    new_self = self.__class__(self.obj, self.name)

    new_self.axis = axis
    return new_self
```

It returns a copy of itself. Now, what the argument passed in between the `()` does, is to instantiate the `axis` member of your new copy. So, this might raise the question as to why it does not matter what value you pass as argument, the resulting indexer is exactly the same. The answer to this question lies in the fact that the superclass `_NDFrameIndexer` is used for multiple child classes.

For the `.loc` method, which calls upon the `_LocIndexer` class, this member does not matter. The `LocIndexer` class is itself a subclass of `_LocationIndexer`, which is a subclass of `_NDFrameIndexer`.

Every time the `axis` is called on by the `_LocationIndexer`, it is defaulted to zero, with no possibility of specifying it yourself. For example I'll refer to one of the functions within the class, with others following suit:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if type(key) is tuple:
        key = tuple(com._apply_if_callable(x, self.obj) for x in key)
        try:
            if self._is_scalar_access(key):
                return self._getitem_scalar(key)
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            pass
        return self._getitem_tuple(key)
    else:
        key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
        return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
```

So, no matter what argument you pass in `.loc(whatever)`, it will be overridden with the default value. Similar behaviour you will see when calling `.iloc`, which calls `_iLocIndexer(_LocationIndexer)` and thus also overrides this `axis` by default.

Where DOES this `axis` come into play then? The answer is: in the deprecated `.ix` method. I have a dataframe of shape `(2187, 5)`, and now define:

```
a = df.ix(0)
b= df.ix(1)
c = df.ix(2)
a[0] == b[0] #True
b[0] == c[0] #True
a[0,1] == b[0,1] #False
```

If you use simple scalar indexing, `axis` is still ignored in this 2-D example, as the `get` method falls back to simple integer-based scalar indexing. However, `a[0,1]` has shape `(2,5)` <- it takes the first two entries along `axis=0`; `b[0,1]` has shape `(2187, 2)` <- it takes the first two entries along `axis=1`; `c[0,1]` returns `ValueError: No axis named 2 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`.

In other words:

> > You can still invoke the **call** method of the _NDFrameIndexer class, as it is used in the _IXIndexer subclass. However: Starting in 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers. The argument passed to **call** for .iloc and .loc is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

For any python object, `()` invokes the `__call__` method, whereas `[]` invokes the `__getitem__` method (unless you are setting a value, in which case it invokes `__setitem__`). In other words `()` and `[]` invoke different methods, so why would you expect them to act the same?